# SX1278 LoRa with Arduino cannot send or receive more than 1 byte

Tags: arduino, lora

I am making a project with LoRa which needs to control 4 servos but through LoRa communication so I sent it like for the first servo it should send values from 0-180 and for the next servo I sent 181 - 361 and goes on for 4 servos! But unfortunately it cannot send values fore that 255 which I guess is 1 byte and if I try to send more that 255 for example 256 it receives as 0 and 257 as 1 and goes on. Is there a commend or way to increase it by a initializing command? Because I know that Lora can send unto 63 bytes.I will attach the code below(Simplified with a simple code):

Sender code(TX)(Arduino UNO):

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <LoRa.h>
    
    int val = 256;
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      while (!Serial);
    
      Serial.println("LoRa Sender");
    
      if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
        Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
        while (1);
      }
    }
    
    void loop() {
      Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
    
      // send packet
      LoRa.beginPacket();
      LoRa.print(val);
      LoRa.endPacket();
    
      delay(500);
    }
```

Receiver Code(RX)(Arduino Mega):

```
   #include <SPI.h>
   #include <LoRa.h>
   
   #define LORA_SS 53
   #define LORA_RST 9
   #define LORA_DIO0 8
   String val;
   
   void setup() {
     pinMode(LORA_SS, OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(LORA_SS, HIGH);
   
     LoRa.setPins(LORA_SS, LORA_RST, LORA_DIO0);
     Serial.begin(9600);
     
     while (!Serial);
   
     Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");
   
     if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
       Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
       while (1);
     }
   }
   
   void loop() {
     // try to parse packet
     int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
     if (packetSize) {
       // received a packet
       Serial.print("Received packet '");
   
       // read packet
       while (LoRa.available()) {
         val = LoRa.read();
        
       }
      
       Serial.print(val.toInt());
       // print RSSI of packet
       Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
       Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
     }
   }
```

Output of the Receiver :

```
Received packet '0' with RSSI -5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `val` in the `int val = LoRa.read();` has a [scope](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/variable-scope-qualifiers/scope/) only within the `while` loop. So when you access it outside of the scope, you get 0.

Move the declaration of the `val` outside of the `while` loop.

```
int val;
while (LoRa.available()) {
   val = LoRa.read();
}
Serial.print(val.toInt());
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience that was a mistake while copy pasting my code(Wrong code) please check it now!

Comment: `Lora.read()` does not return a String, it return an `int`. Do `Serial.print((char)Lora.read())` to see it yourself.

Comment: But when i give Serial.print((char)Lora.read()) how will i compare the input i need to write the incoming value to a servo

Comment: Your question is why you are getting 0 instead of the value you send, so forget about the servo and find out why you are getting 0 first.